# Let $X$ be normal with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$, let $Y$ be uniform on $(0,\pi)$. Find the density of $Z=X+a \cos(Y)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be normal with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$, let $Y$ be uniform on $(0,\pi)$ and let $a$ be a real number. Assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent . Find the density of $Z=X+a \cos(Y)$.

I just need to find $P(Z \leq t)=\int_0^\pi \int_{-\infty}^{a \cos(Y)+t} f_X (x) \frac{1}{\pi} \, dx \, dy$ and take the derivative with respect to $t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density of the sum of independent random variables is the convolution of their two densities.  The random point $a(\cos Y, \sin Y)$ is uniformly distributed on the circle.  The length of the arc of a circle whose points have $y$-coordinates in any set $A$ on the $y$-axis is
$$
\int_A a\,d\theta = \int_A \frac{a\,dy}{\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}.
$$
Find the normalizing constant $c$ that will make
$$
\int_{-a}^a \frac{c\,dy}{\sqrt{a^2-y^2}} =1
$$
and you'll have the density function of the random variable $Y$.

The convolution is
$$
f(z) = \int_{-a}^a \frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2-y^2}} \cdot \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(z-y)^2/2} \,dy.
$$
I'm inclined to doubt there is a closed form for this.

Comment: PS: Above I assumed $\sigma=1$.  For other values of $\sigma$, mutatis mutandis....